# Java SimpleFileServer disable directory listing

Tags: java, httpserver, fileserver

For a minimalistic SimpleFileServer pseudocode below, how to disable directory listing?

```
var server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 2)
server.createContext("/file", SimpleFileServer.createFileHandler(Path.of("d:\file")));
server.start();
```

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I would think that this question would benefit from more detail, more *real* code, and removal of the GitHub link. All pertinent information should be in the question itself, such as a [mre] code post, and not in a link.

Comment: Oh, I thought I only use jdk classes. Did u see any legal issues?

Comment: What do you mean by "legal issues"? This site is a software Q&A site and does not delve into legal issues, other than that intellectual property rights must be respected. That's it.

Comment: To be safe I am removing github redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put an index file (index.html or index.htm) in the directory, then that will be served, rather than the directory contents.

One more thing: you probably want a / at the end of the context path (so "/file/") as per the note in the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#createContext(java.lang.String,com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler)):

> The path should generally, but is not required to, end with '/'. If the path does not end with '/', eg such as with "/foo" then this would match requests with a path of "/foobar" or "/foo/bar".

Alternatively:

```java
var server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 2);
var fileHandler = SimpleFileServer.createFileHandler(Path.of("d:\file"));
server.createContext("/file/", (exchange) -> {
    if (exchange.getHttpContext().getPath().equals(exchange.getRequestURI().getPath())) {
        try (exchange) {
            exchange.setAttribute("request-path", "could not resolve request URI path");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(404, 0);
        }
    } else {
        fileHandler.handle(exchange);
    }
});
server.start();
```

Comment: Thank you. Before "fileHandler.handle(exchange);", adding "if (file not exists) return;" helped a lot.